# Best way to import delimited and paginated data with Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, numpy, pandas

I've got data files which repeat their 4 header lines every so often as a form of pagination.  Because of this I can't use automatic import methods because these extra header lines get in the way.  I can read line by line, checking if each line is a header, check only for the first line of the header and skip the following 3 lines, or simply parse the whole file with a regex that matches 6 continuous columns of data, which will match every data row and skip the headers handily.

I was wondering if there was a way to import the data with pandas, numpy, the csv library or some other trickery I haven't thought of.

While regex is pretty quick, I'm about to do a bunch of batch processing and trade studies and I want my post-processing to be able to quickly handle dozens or hundreds of files to show comparisons.

I just realized the number of lines per page seems to always be 55, so maybe some simple counting will work, or modulus - I'll ask the question anyway, because I'm curious if anyone has found a library that deals with repeated headers or "chunked" data like this.

I'll add a modulus-based solution for fixed-length pages as an answer...

Thanks for any other ideas!

Edit: Here's an example of the format... in reality there are 55 lines of data per page, but I limited it to 5 for brevity.  And, yes, there is a 1 in the first column at the beginning of each header, so that could be used as well.  I'm pretty sure that `1` used to be a FormFeed character in older versions of the code, which makes sense for old school pagination coming out of a FORTRAN-based code running on mainframes.

```
1  DATE: 03/10/14      Analysis Title                                                             

     TIME    PRESSURE      MDOT       THRUST        PT        AB           D
      SEC      PSIA      LBM/SEC       LBF         PSIA      IN^2         IN
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
   11.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
   11.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
1  DATE: 03/10/14      Analysis Title                                                             

     TIME    PRESSURE      MDOT       THRUST        PT        AB           D
      SEC      PSIA      LBM/SEC       LBF         PSIA      IN^2         IN
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
1  DATE: 03/10/14      Analysis Title                                                             

     TIME    PRESSURE      MDOT       THRUST        PT        AB           D
      SEC      PSIA      LBM/SEC       LBF         PSIA      IN^2         IN
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
    1.769    1372.02      1220.0     363622.4    1332.78    60361.37     0.050
```

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the data? Would help a lot for people trying to answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I meant to do that - added the example...

Comment: use `grep --invert-match TIME|SEC|DATE` as a one-liner pre-processing step. much easier than doing it python. I would recommend chain your tools: grep | python-script of you > analysed_data.dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for fixed number of column and fixed lines per page.  I thought I'd go ahead and wrap it into a class since that's how I'm using it (need to load, process, plot, save to other formats, etc so a class makes sense).  Using modulus to check whether on a header line I thought was elegant.

```
import os
import numpy as np


class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Data, self).__init__()
        self.time = None
        self.pressure = None

    def load(self, filename):

        #Data Properties
        cols = 7
        lines_per_page = 59
        header_lines = 4

        #Initialize Data
        data = np.empty([0, cols])

        #Open the file
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:

            #Traverse the file's lines
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):

                #Check whether this is a header line
                if i % lines_per_page >= header_lines:

                    #Split line into columns, convert to float, convert to numpy array, shape as a row
                    linedata = np.array(map(float, line.split())).reshape(1, cols)

                    #Add the row to the bottom of the data
                    data = np.vstack([data, linedata])

        self.time = data[:, 0]
        self.pressure = data[:, 1]
```

Comment: I fixed a bug here which was actually causing me crashing and grief that I can't believe propagated this long.  `i % lines_per_page > header_lines` will fail on the line just after the header.  Instead it should be `>=` so that when the modulus is 4, which occurs when i=4, which is the 5th line, the line is included.